# Data entry form with automatic submission after every entry

Tags: google-sheets, automation, data-entry

I want to make a data entry form where I enter unlimited data in a single cell (C2) and it auto submit, then every data entered in that cell will be listed in a range (A8:A1000) with timestamp in each entry. Thank you in advance.

I made a sample template.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zzImiEF5IGQWrhAPyvJmktdhVef8REg-B-I_5qRBuoc/edit#gid=0

Haven't tried to make any forms yet.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.